# activemq not compatible with spring 4.3.6

Tags: spring, maven, jms, activemq-classic

activemq not compatibale with spring 4.3.6. And i cant change spring version. I use following dependencies in pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where activemq show dependency on 4.3.9 i also tried 5.14.4 which have dependency on 4.1.9.

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you using the all jar and mixing in a different spring dep?

Comment: You can use maven exclusions to exclude the spring dependencies from the ActiveMQ dependency. So you can control the spring JARs you want to use

Comment: @Tim should i use activemq-core only?

Answer (score 1):

I used client dependency only and now its working.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This does not have spring dependencies. Either we can use exclusion if we are using all jar or can use specific dependencies needed for project. Thanks for help.